# switching `<Down>` and `<C-n>` in popup menu

Tags: ins-completion

I'd like to switch the behaviour of the `<Down>` and `<C-n>` keys when the popup menu (like from omnicompletion) is visible (and `<Up>`/`<C-p>` respectively).

The following two mappings work (actually only in neovim; in vim they insert arbitrary lines with single letters on each keystroke):

```
inoremap <expr> <Down>     pumvisible() ? "\<C-n>" : "\<Down>"
inoremap <expr> <Up>       pumvisible() ? "\<C-p>" : "\<Up>"
```

The following don't

```
inoremap <expr> <C-n>      pumvisible() ? "\<Down>" : "\<C-n>"
inoremap <expr> <C-p>      pumvisible() ? "\<Up>" : "\<C-p>"
```

What am I doing wrong? I tried it with `--no-plugin -u NONE` to assure that they don't conflict with some other setting or plugin, but that is not the case.